# PL SQL Select Into Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is the code I am executing.

```
declare
cid number;
orid number;
olid number;

begin
cid := '2';
orid := '1006';
olid := '4';

select s_customer_t.customer_id, s_order_t.order_id, s_order_line_t.product_id into cid, orid, olid
from s_customer_t, s_order_t, s_order_line_t
where s_customer_t.customer_id = s_order_t.customer_id 
and s_order_t.order_id = s_order_line_t.order_id;

dbms_output.put_line('Customer ID is'  || cid || ', Order ID is' || orid || ', Product ID is' || olid);

end;
```

This is what I want:

> Customer ID is 2, Order ID is 1006, Product ID is 4

And this what I get:

> Customer ID is2, Order ID is1006, Product ID is4

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that represents your issue; a description of what "is not correct" including the complete error messages; and the expected output for your PL/SQL block. Just saying that it "is not correct" is not helpful as it doesn't tell us what is wrong or what you expect to be right so please help us to help you by giving us all the information necessary to understand the problem.

Comment: Assuming that the joins are correct (and you really, really want to be learning the ANSI standard join syntax `x join y on` rather than having a list of tables in the `from` clause and a bunch of join predicates in the `where` clause), do you expect that the query will return multiple rows?  I'd expect so-- presumably you have multiple orders and order lines.  If so, you can't use a `select into` since that requires the query to return exactly 1 row.

Comment: Maybe you want to add a `where` clause that uses the variables you declared to limit the query to a single row (in which case printing out the values you pre-defined is pretty pointless).  Or more likely you want to do something like write a loop that iterates over a number of rows that are returned by the query and prints out the values from each row.

Comment: Since you said it doesn't work, what is the error you are getting? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I took a chance editing the question to be concise and to the point, which I think is actually "how to I format the output with the appropriate white space". Just roll back the edit if I made the wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Customer ID is'  || cid || ', Order ID is' || orid || ', Product ID is' || olid);
```

to

```
dbms_output.put_line('Customer ID is '  || cid || ', Order ID is ' || orid || ', Product ID is ' || olid);
```